# Detecting if mouse click is before or after an element

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to insert an content at the position a mouse is clicked.  Looking at the following:

```
<div id="parentDiv">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
</div>
```

I know I can get the div that was clicked on with code like this:

```
function handleMouseClickEvent(e) {
    var evt = e ? e:window.event;
    var targ = evt.target ? evt.target:evt.srcElement;
}
```

However if someone clicks in between div1 and div2 then the ***targ*** will be ***parentDiv***.

Is there a way to detect that the click was before or after a child element so I can insert content at the exact place that was clicked?

Comment: What about inserting one blank tag between div2 and 3? and if clicked on that one you can insert content

Comment: The example was simplified for the question, but the actual page I'm trying to do this on has many elements of different types and are  beyond my control.

Comment: But this can be done using repeater control you only have to get element id and you need a click where it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the coordinates of the click to do the check.

Instead of handling the event on the item you can handle the event on the container and the iterate over the children and checking `child.offsetTop` and `child.offsetHeight` to find the first child that starts after the mouse click.

Once you know that you can decide if you want to consider that click a click on the child, or a click between e child and next or previous one e.g. by considering

- `y < child.offsetTop + child.offsetHeight*0.1` between child and previous
- `y > child.offsetTop + child.offsetHeight*0.9` between child and next
- otherwise is a click on the child

Answer (score 0):

You can store the **`evt.target`** and check this when you click next.  For example

```
var elementClicked;
function handleMouseClickEvent(e) {
    if (elementClicked == "parent") {
       //-----handle based on your condition
    }
    else if (elementClicked == "div1"){
       //-----handle based on your condition    
    }
    else {
    var evt = e ? e:window.event;
    var targ = evt.target ? evt.target:evt.srcElement;
    elementClicked = targ;
    }
}
```

Hope you understand the logic.

Comment: I'm not sure if I worded my question clearly enough.  The problem I'm having is that unless you click inside div1,div2, or div3 the target will always be parentDiv.  I'd like to insert content **after** div2 if the click was in between div2 and div3.  Clicking between and outside those divs will show the target as parentDiv, but not which child element the click was before or after.